# how to inserting multiple rows into mysql with one INSERT statement using PHP implode function?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to insert multiple rows with only one INSERT INTO statement using the implode function. I use "keluhanpg" and "mkpg" for multiple values. and "mkpg" uses implode because I use multiple selected data and I implode with comma. like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwN8L.png)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once('koneksi.php');

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $kodepg         = $_POST['kodepg'];
    $noformpg       = $_POST['noformpg'];
    $waktupg        = $_POST['waktupg'];
    $deptpg         = $_POST['deptpg'];
    $lokasipg       = $_POST['lokasipg'];
    $merkpg         = $_POST['merkpg'];
    $tahunpg        = $_POST['tahunpg'];
    $op             = isset($_POST['oppg']) && is_array($_POST['oppg']) ? $_POST['oppg'] : [];
    $oppg           = implode(", ", $op);
    $keluhanpg      = isset($_POST['keluhanpg']) && is_array($_POST['keluhanpg']) ? $_POST['keluhanpg'] : [];
    $mk             = isset($_POST['mkpg']) && is_array($_POST['mkpg']) ? $_POST['mkpg'] : [];
    $mkpg           = implode(", ", $mk);
    $shiftpg        = $_POST['shiftpg'];
    $statuspg       = $_POST['statuspg'];
    
    foreach ($_POST['keluhanpg'] as $key => $value){
        $sql= "INSERT INTO tb_pg_cs (kode_pg,noform_pg,waktu_pg,dept_pg,lokasi_pg,merk_pg,tahun_pg,op_pg,keluhan_pg,mk_pg,shift_pg,status_pg) VALUES ('" . $kodepg . "','".$noformpg . "','".$waktupg . "','".$deptpg . "','".$lokasipg . "','".$merkpg . "','".$tahunpg . "','".$oppg . "','".$_POST['keluhanpg'][$key] . "','".$mkpg . "','".$shiftpg . "','".$statuspg . "')";
        $sql1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    }
    
    if($sql1){
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Data added successfully';
    }else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Something went wrong while adding';
    }
    
    }   

    header("location: ".$base_url."index.php?page=pengajuan");
?>
```

the input successfully exited but the "mkpg" data was merged into one. like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2wnu.png)

how to write code to process input correctly?

Comment: What is your MySQL precise version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @Akina my MySQL precise version 8.0.3

Answer (score 0):

> my MySQL precise version 8.0.3 – vivie

Your version allows to use recursive CTE in SELECT part of INSERT .. SELECT. So you can parse your CSV provided by PHP and store it as a lot of separate rows.

This can be done, for example, using

```sql
INSERT INTO test (single_arg, csv_arg)
WITH RECURSIVE
source_data AS ( SELECT @single_arg single_arg,
                        @csv_arg csv_arg ),
cte AS ( SELECT single_arg,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv_arg, ',', 1) single_from_csv,
                TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(csv_arg, ',', 1) FROM csv_arg)) slack_from_csv
         FROM source_data
         UNION ALL
         SELECT single_arg,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(slack_from_csv, ',', 1),
                TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(slack_from_csv, ',', 1) FROM slack_from_csv))
         FROM cte
         WHERE TRIM(slack_from_csv) <> '' )
SELECT single_arg, 
       single_from_csv
FROM cte;
```

See [DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ff72760cac5a9246bcbc698f8be492c) (contains some explanations).